# Order by name in Sankey chart

Tags: google-visualization, googlevis, sankey-diagram

Is it possible to sort by name using sankey? For example:

**Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/Khrys/1s3shf2m/

```
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'From');
    data.addColumn('string', 'To');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
    data.addRows([
      [ 'A', 'Mango', 5 ],
      [ 'A', 'Mango', 7 ],
      [ 'A', 'Apple', 6 ],
      [ 'B', 'Coconut', 2 ],
      [ 'B', 'Mango', 9 ],
      [ 'B', 'Pineapple', 4 ]
    ]);

    // Sets chart options.
    var options = {
      width: 600,
    };

    // Instantiates and draws our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.Sankey(document.getElementById('sankey_basic'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

I am expecting a output of the right side to be (from top to bottom): Apple, Coconut, Mango, Pineapple

Thanks

Answer (score 21):

Set iterations to 0, and the diagram should draw according to the input order of the data.

Example:

```
var options = {
  height: 400,
  width: 400,
  sankey: {
iterations: 0,
      }
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

As answered by Daniel from Google itself in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/Tsyj8ZQ8IMU

> Sorry, we don't have sufficient control over the generated order of
>   the output nodes.